# What's the best way to purge duplicate partial value from list<string>()?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to purge duplicate value from the list and I'm not sure of a best way to do this.

```
List<string> sqlOrderBy = new List<string>();

sqlOrderBy.Add("Trim ASC");
sqlOrderBy.Add("Year ASC");
sqlOrderBy.Add("Make DESC");
sqlOrderBy.Add("Year DESC");
sqlOrderBy.Add("Model ASC");
sqlOrderBy.Add("Make ASC");
```

What I'm trying to figure out is to search for duplicate prefix values like "Year" and "Make" and keep the last one in the list but purge the earlier one regardless of the "ASC" or "DESC" value...  What I want it to do is this...

```
//Trim ASC
//Year DESC
//Model ASC
//Make ASC
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to group it by the first part, then take the last entry in each group:

```
List<string> query = sqlOrderBy.GroupBy(x => x.Split(' ')[0])
                               .Select(g => g.Last())
                               .ToList();
```

Running that with your sample data, I get:

```
Trim ASC
Year DESC
Make ASC
Model ASC
```

Is that what you wanted?

EDIT: To comment on ordering, this will return the elements not in their original order, but in the order that the first part was specified. If you want the original order, it can be done but it's a bit funky:

```
List<string> query = sqlOrderBy.AsEnumerable()
                               .Reverse()
                               .GroupBy(x => x.Split(' ')[0])
                               .Select(g => g.First())
                               .Reverse()
                               .ToList();
```

(The `AsEnumerable()` call is just to remove `List<T>.Reverse` from the equation - we're not trying to call that.)

So we're grouping from the *end*, which means the groups will appear in the reverse order, and then we can reverse the results again. This gives us results of:

```
Trim ASC
Year DESC
Model ASC
Make ASC
```

Comment: Is `GroupBy` guaranteed to preserve order?

Comment: @PaulPhillips: Yes (in LINQ to Objects) although it may not be the order the OP wants: "The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`."

Comment: @fletchsod Try mine. Not sure about what ordering `DistinctBy` uses though.

Comment: Hey Jon, would writing a `Comparator` be any good for this? And what if I wanted to keep the entry that had `DESC` for example?

Comment: @fletchsod: Did you read to the end of the post and try the second form?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I posted the reply before you posted the edited post.  :-)  I noticed the Reverse() is not support in .NET framework 4.5 unless I specify a value in Reverse()  [Reverse(value)].

Comment: @fletchsod: You really didn't (for edit 2)... my edit was a while ago although you may have *started* writing your comment before I edited the post. I made a further edit though, which fixes the `Reverse()` issue - it was `List<T>.Reverse` getting in the way.

Comment: @Bob.: No, I don't think a `Comparer` (which is what I think you meant) would help much here. I'm not sure about the second part of your comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Let me give this a try and see how it goes..  I see AsEmerable() now.

Comment: It looks good when testing it.  I think it will work well!  Time will tell if it falls short.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Using [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and `DistinctBy`:

```
sqlOrderBy.AsEnumerable().Reverse().DistinctBy(n => n.Split(' ')[0]);
```